# How to log each application activity in android?

Tags: android

Hello I want to log application activity information on my android phone, I just need 2 things, the start time of the application and the end time of the application.

I just want to know for how much time a particular application/activity was running.

Say for example a user launched music player and after some time closed it? I just want to know how long the music player opened, or if he is talking on phone how long that activity to took after finishing?

My application will run as service, logging all this information is sqlLite. Once my application started it should log all the above information for each activity triggered there after.

Please let me know how can i do this??

I know about logcat but i want to know how they log this things or how can i code something similar??

Thanks
Pranay

Comment: you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html to manage the application lifecycle and determine if the app is running or is in background. To manage each activity data , handle it on  the onStart() and onStop() of the activity.